# Why does not Slick slider work inside a form tag?

Tags: php, jquery, css, plugins, slick.js

https://magenta-spirit.codio.io/ - if remove tag form everything is ok. But inside form tag slider does not work. Console is empty. What is the reason?
Slick:

```
$().ready(function(e) {
$('.calc-photos-slider').slick({
    dots: true,
    infinite: false,
    speed: 500,
    fade: false,
    slide: 'li',
    cssEase: 'linear',
    centerMode: true,
    slidesToShow: 1,
    variableWidth: true,
    autoplay: false,
    autoplaySpeed: 4000,
    responsive: [{
        breakpoint: 800,
        settings: {
            arrows: false,
            centerMode: false,
            centerPadding: '40px',
            variableWidth: false,
            slidesToShow: 1,
            dots: true
        },
        breakpoint: 1200,
        settings: {
            arrows: false,
            centerMode: false,
            centerPadding: '40px',
            variableWidth: false,
            slidesToShow: 1,
            dots: true

        }
    }],
    customPaging: function(slider, i) {
        return '<button class="tab">' + $('.slick-thumbs li:nth-child(' + (i + 1) + ')').html() + '</button>';
    }
});
});
```

Comment: It works for me at the moment. Did you remove the form? I'm asking since there is another form wrapping everything. Are you trying to add a form inside a form , if so that's not going to work.

Comment: I have not removed tag and slider still does not work, what browser do you use? I have this message on a page: Unexpected system error 81fd5c70-b96b-4e49-b952-792cf4b1b08b. There is only one form tag.

Comment: Chrome, Firefox, IE - it works for me everywhere. Here is a video: https://streamable.com/ek08k You might mean the thumbs issue. Add `type="button"` to the buttons.

Comment: Great! Added type="button" and this helped, thank you (yes, I meant thumbs issue)! How to rate your answer?

Answer (score 0):

Issue resolved, We just changed left and right button tag  to anchor tag and issue resolved.

```
    Just change 
return '<button class="tab">' + $('.slick-thumbs li:nth-child(' + (i + 1) + ')').html() + '</button>';

to 

return '<a class="tab">' + $('.slick-thumbs li:nth-child(' + (i + 1) + ')').html() + '</a>';


This will work for you

prevArrow: '<button class="slick-prev"></button>',
nextArrow: '<button class="slick-next"></button>',

to

prevArrow: '< a class="slick-prev"> <i class="ion-ios-arrow-back"></i >< /a >',
nextArrow: '<a class="slick-next">< i class="ion-ios-arrow-forward"> </i > </a >',
```